# MS Access SQL: How to query, first row data of an hour is subtracted from the first row of the next hour

Tags: ms-access, timestamp

Please Run the code to see the table and expected output.

I need to separate the data by hourly produce. I am using MS ACCESS database where some options are not supported. I have used dateadd, datediff in my query. I have added my code as well.

```css
    table {
      font-family: arial, sans-serif;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 100%;
    }

    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #dddddd;
      text-align: left;
      padding: 8px;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #dddddd;
    }
```

```html
    <HTML>
    <body>
    <B>GIVEN TABLE:</B><BR><br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>TIME_STAMP</th>
        <th>PRODUCE</th>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 9:00:00 AM</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 9:04:54 AM</td>
        <td>120</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 9:04:54 AM</td>
        <td>130</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 9:28:57 AM</td>
        <td>150</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 9:29:14 AM</td>
        <td>170</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 9:29:23 AM</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 10:00:00 AM</td>
        <td>300</td>
      </tr>
    </table><br>
     <B>EXPECTED OUTPUT:</B><BR><br>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>HOUR_STAMP</th>
        <th>HOURLY_PRODUCE</th>
      </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 9:00:00 AM</td>
        <td>100</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21-Nov-20 10:00:00 AM</td>
        <td>200</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>

    </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

> DIFFERENCE BETWEEN DATA BY FIRST ROW OF EVERY HOUR. ON 21-NOV-2020 9AM-10 AM TOTAL PRODUCE IS (300-100)=200

```
SELECT DateAdd("h",DateDiff("h",0,TIME_STAMP),0) AS HOUR_STAMP FROM 001;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way but I've come up with a query which should work or at least give you more ideas.

In this example, the query is getting the data from a table called TABLE_DATA which contains fields TIME_STAMP and PRODUCE. The query groups the data by the hour (HOUR_STAMP), shows the first produce for each hour (FIRST_PRODUCE), shows the first produce for the previous hour (PREVIOUS_FIRST_PRODUCE), and lastly shows the difference between the two (HOURLY_PRODUCE).

```
SELECT Format([TIME_STAMP],"dd-mmm-yy hh:""00"":""00""") AS HOUR_STAMP, First(PRODUCE) AS FIRST_PRODUCE, Nz(DLookUp("PRODUCE","TABLE_DATA","Format(TIME_STAMP, 'ddmmyyhh') = " & Format(DateAdd("h",-1,[HOUR_STAMP]),'ddmmyyhh')),0) AS PREVIOUS_FIRST_PRODUCE, [FIRST_PRODUCE]-[PREVIOUS_FIRST_PRODUCE] AS HOURLY_PRODUCE
FROM TABLE_DATA
GROUP BY Format([TIME_STAMP],"dd-mmm-yy hh:""00"":""00""");
```